# OpenMP 5.0 Memory allocation

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to use an example from the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-TR5-final.pdf) on page 64:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int basic_default2(int n)
{
  const int success=1, failure=0;
  int retval;
  omp_memspace_t *my_mspace;
  omp_allocator_t *my_allocator;
  double *buffer;

  my_mspace = omp_init_memspace(&omp_default_memtraits);
  my_allocator = omp_init_allocator(my_mspace, &omp_default_alloctraits);
  buffer = omp_alloc(n * sizeof(*buffer), my_allocator);

  if ( buffer == NULL ){
    fprintf("Could not allocate space using default traits\n");
    retval = failure;
  }else{
    do_work(buffer, n);
    omp_free(buffer, my_allocator);
    retval = success;
  }

  omp_destroy_allocator(my_allocator);
  omp_destroy_mspace(my_mspace);
}
```

According to the [OpenMp 5.0 requirements](https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/) this should work. 
I am using GNU 9.1.0 compiler and the -fopenmp flag.

Unfortunately, the type `omp_allocator_t` is unknown by the compiler.

Comment: _"From GCC 9.1, OpenMP 5.0 is **partially** supported for C and C++."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a 2017 Technical Report, not the [OpenMP 5.0 standard](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmp.html), and the interface has evolved since the TR (which does say "Expires January 4th, 2018" on the cover!)

In the standard, the return type from `omp_init_allocator` is `omp_allocator_handle_t`.

Note, too, that many of the other names have also changed, so your code needs other changes as well (for instance there is no `omp_init_memspace` call any longer).

The allocation section of the standard is [here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse35.html#x211-10400003.7).